# Jquery to navigate through div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to show a div based on the `onclick` event of an link.

1. First Click - Hide remaining div's (meaning `div1`) and Show `div2`
2. Second Click - Hide remaining div's and Show `div3`
3. Third Click - Hide remaining div's and show `div4`
4. Fourth Click - Hide remaining div's and show `div5`
5. Fifth Click = Hide remaining div's and show `div6`

In the code `div2`, `div3`, `div4`, `div5`, `div6` display is set to none.

```html
<div id='div1'> 
  <!-- content -->
</div>
<div id='div2' style="display:none;"> 
  <!-- content -->
</div>
<div id='div3' style="display:none;"> 
  <!-- content -->
</div>
<div id='div4' style="display:none;"> 
  <!-- content -->
</div>
<div id='div5' style="display:none;"> 
  <!-- content -->
</div>
<div id='div6' style="display:none;"> 
  <!-- content -->
</div>
<button id="button">Next</button>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include your HTML and current attempt at writing the JS

Comment: I edited the question. I don't have JS.

Comment: well you say you need js or jquery for this. What have you tried?

Comment: Well that's why i asked for help here. If I had something I would post it, but I don't.

Comment: Then perhaps you should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Dude you seriously need to know what to ask and what to try and what to learn on your own. There is a flaw in your approach. Go learn yourself first. Atleast give it a try.

Comment: Well you should know, StackOverflow is not a code making site. We help you debug/improve your code but we don't make ( unless you are lucky and someone does ) code from scratch. There are freelancing sites for that ( for money, of course )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

**EDIT**

If you want to go to new page after last div just add `else` statement and add some attribute to send url.

```js
$("#button").on('click', function() {
  var visible = $("[id^=div]:visible"),
    number = parseInt(visible.attr('id').substr(3)) + 1,
    nextDiv = $("#div" + number);
  if (nextDiv.length > 0) {
    visible.hide();
    nextDiv.show();
  } else {
    location.href = $(this).attr("data-href");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1'>
  Content 1
</div>
<div id='div2' style="display:none;">
  Content 2
</div>
<div id='div3' style="display:none;">
  Content 3
</div>
<div id='div4' style="display:none;">
  Content 4
</div>
<div id='div5' style="display:none;">
  Content 5
</div>
<div id='div6' style="display:none;">
  Content 6
</div>
<button id="button" data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Next</button>
```

Comment: Somehow it gets stuck in the second div. It wont go through the third one and so on.

Comment: What browser are you using? And does it happen in snippet? Because I tried on chrome, firefox and edge and it worked on all of them.

Comment: It works fine here. When I try to implement it in my code it wont work there. But thank you for your help.

Comment: Than perhaps you have other elements with id that starts with `div`. To make sure that this code applies only to those elements you can add a class (for example `newClass`), and in js change this line `var number = parseInt($("[id^=div]:visible").attr('id').substr(3)) + 1;` to this `var number = parseInt($("[id^=div].newClass:visible").attr('id').substr(3)) + 1;`

Comment: I tried to add class. I tried also to change the ID of div to something else, did the changes in JS as well but still the same thing it stops in Div2 it wont move to the next one.

Comment: Then add please all your html. And also, did you check the console? Perhaps there is some erorr that stops it.

Comment: Solved dude. Thanks a Lot. It works fine now. I just had to do some html changes. Thanks for not moaning like the rest but instead you helped me.

Comment: If I am now at the last div (div6), when I press again button I want to go to another page? What should I change?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *go to another page*? Do you want the button to act like a `<a>` link?

Comment: yep like <a> but only when I am in the last div.

Comment: @Skofiar I edited answer

Comment: it works fine. Thanks a lot! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var counter = 1;
$("#button").bind("click",{},function(e){
   
counter++;
console.log("#div"+counter)
$(".sameType").addClass("displayNone");
   $("#div"+counter).removeClass("displayNone");
   if(counter==6){
   counter=0;
   }
})
```

```css
.sameType{
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
background:#ff9900;
height:50px; width:50px; 
margin:0;
}
.displayNone{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1' class='sameType'> 
  <!-- content -->
  1
</div>

<div id='div2' class='sameType displayNone'> 
  <!-- content -->
  2
</div>

<div id='div3' class='sameType displayNone'> 
  <!-- content -->
  3
</div>
<div id='div4' class='sameType displayNone'> 
  <!-- content -->
  4
</div>
<div id='div5' class='sameType displayNone'> 
  <!-- content -->
  5
</div>
<div id='div6' class='sameType displayNone'> 
  <!-- content -->
  6
</div>
<button id="button">Next</button>
```

You can use the above.